# In Eclipse JDT Java parser, is it possible to traverse the AST node by node without the using of visitors?

Tags: java, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt, tree-traversal

The standard way to access information on Nodes through the Eclipse JDT API is with Visitor's pattern. For example:

```
unit.accept(new MyVisitorAdapter<Object>() {
  @Override public void visit(MethodCallExpr node, Object arg) {
    System.out.println("found method call: " + node.toString());
  }
}, null);
```

In this case, to visit a node I need to specify what type of node I'm interested (`MethodCallExpr` for this case). But, to proceed to access node information in a generic way, I should override all the `visit()` method, potentially enumerating every kind of node available in the Eclipse JDT API. A full example of where it is done is found [here](https://github.com/isbadawi/coverage-example/blob/master/src/main/java/io/badawi/coverage/CoverageInstrumentationVisitor.java).

In this context, although not exactly in the same domain of Code Coverage, I would like to have control over the traversal done by the Eclipse JDT Java Parser. I would like to walk through the AST nodes, potentially passing by all of them, selecting what I want, but without to restrict to a type, as shown in the code above. Is it possible? Is there a standard way to do that through the Eclipse JDT API?

Comment: Why without visitors?

Comment: In fact, there is no problem to use a visitor pattern, if the API has the visitor I want, but it doesn't seem to be the case... So I wanna pass by the nodes extracting some information and without to depend on the node type.

Comment: You should describe your actual problem ("no suitable visitor in the API") and post the code you have tried so far. Visitors are the usual way to traverse the AST.

Comment: My problem is someway related to [this another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51164508/is-there-any-kind-of-line-visitor-in-eclipse-jdt-java-parser-if-there-is-not?noredirect=1#comment89328444_51164508) that I've posted. But you should have in mind that visitors are just one of the options (the default) to explore information in the AST. I just wanna know if someone has tried another standard solution via Eclipse API or have a good tip to do it by hand before I try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Here's a humble piece of advice. Stop theorizing and post some code. For instance the Java code you compile, how you do it with the Eclipse JDT API and which information you actually want to extract.

Comment: It is not about theorizing, neither about what is wrong with my code. There are lots of solutions using visitors to access information in AST node. I know how to do that way, it just doesn't fit well. [Here](http://ismail.badawi.io/blog/2013/05/03/writing-a-code-coverage-tool/) there is a possible idea to do it the standard way with visitors and apply to my problem (see that the author explicitly enumerate all the visitors he is interested... it is not what I want).

Comment: It is not about code coverage but I need a similar kind of mapping so I can access AST nodes associated to each line of the source code file and do some processing on them. If no one knows a better way to traverse the Eclipse AST without using the visitor's models, of course it will be one of my start points for a workaround.

Comment: You might be interested in my 2002 paper on how to build branch coverage for arbitrary languages: http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf   Doesn't use visitors :-}  .. but it does require walking the tree once to apply probe-insertion code where appropriate; that insertion step also captures the  line number of the probe insertion point, so you don't have to visit the file "line by line" to instrument it.

Comment: @lexicore, although I still think that this question is not about point problems in my code, I think the last edit would satisfy your suggestion to give some code example since you have marked the question "off-topic". Please consider it in the new format and suggest improvements, since for me the discussion and the contributions of other users were very helpful and I suppose it would be for others in the same situation than mine...

Comment: @VictorSobreira I have repeatedly asked you to post the MCVE. Which is not just to find problems in your code but also to let people play with the code and help you with a solution. You have repeatedly ignored my request. Finally, I had enough and decided that this deserves a close vote. Four other users supported my decision. From my point of view, you have still not provided a [MCVE] so I see no reason to reopen your question. This is my last comment here, if you want to discuss it further on, please take it to [meta].

Comment: @lexicore You can do anything you want, especially in your position as an older user with high reputation. You just have to think about the real purpose of this site. I'm a new user, but I'm not a new developer, neither a young one. I'm humble to ask something when I don't know. It was what I did when posting this question. My problem was solved, the answer from another user was enough for me (it was enough for him also, because he understood my problem and gave me the right direction, simple like that, It is done).

Comment: I understand that in some cases, the code is essential to understand the question, problem, etc, and for that MCVE that you pointed can be applied (thanks for the suggestion, I'm learning on it). But it is not the case, from Help Center I found [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and I suppose this question satisfies it (point me where it breaks, so I can fix).

Comment: Even considering that I tried to improve the question, you insist that it is not enough. It is possible that I have been using StackOverflow for years, but I just start to contribute with questions and this is the first reception I have from someone who should stimulate and help in the growing of the community with good colaborations... You and other users of high reputation have to think seriously about it... Are you really trying to extend the help I receive to others with this decision?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care about node types, override any of `ASTVisitor.preVisit(ASTNode)`, `ASTVisitor.preVisit2(ASTNode)`, `ASTVisitor.postVisit(ASTNode)`.

Comment: After running some tests, I can get what I need with ASTVisitor.preVisit( ASTNode ). Although it still uses the visitor model, it really passes by all nodes and allows to access the information in the same order of the lines in source code file. Thanks a lot Stephan!